# Portable Power Station Solar Input Limitations - Workaround?

Tags: solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I'm considering buying this unit for backup energy + solar charging:

https://www.ecoflow.com/us/delta-pro-portable-power-station

Now, the max input is 1600W with 150V and 15A max.  This is acceptable if the sun shines bright and I'm getting the 1600W into the system.  However, that is obviously not always the case. You need to overdesign your solar array to get an average of 1600W into your system due to cloud overage etc...  Thus, my problem is I cannot connect 150V, 30A setup to the device as it could potentially blow a fuse or not be compatible.

Is  there anything that can be done upfront to accept higher amps, and discard anything above 15A?  So that I only feed 15A into the power station?  Throw away any excess energy?  Maybe put a Victron solar charge controller and feed that into the power bank?  I know this is a long shot, just asking if something like this is possible?

Comment: There's no documentation on the website

Comment: It has more to do with the principle... the specs are as given here.  150V, 15A max solar input.  My question is what if I want to feed 30A and same voltage?  Need some way of discarding excess amps ?  This is in order to overdesign the system for cloudy days.  This will obviously be a separate device that sits between solar panels and power station

Comment: The source won't force 30A into the battery.  If you have a 150V source that can provide 30A, the charger will draw 15A from it to charge the battery.  If this is not clear to you, then I suggest you consult a local company to have your system setup.

Comment: @JRE I'm trying to learn, so no point in getting someone to do it for me.  So are you saying if I have a solar panel configuration giving 150V, 30A, then the solar charge controller will only draw 15A?  Meaning I cannnot "overload" it and cause damage ?

Comment: The outlets in your house can deliver 15A, but your phone charger uses less than 1A.   Your TV doesn't draw 15A all the time when it is on.  The outlets deliver 120VAC at up to 15A.  Similarly, the solar system will deliver 150V at up to 30A - but your battery charger doesn't have to take all 30A.

Comment: Learning is good, but starting with things that can go boom and burn down your house make poor learning projects.

Comment: @JRE that makes sense.   Happy to know this as I can then "oversize" my installation.  Just need to make sure the voltage stays under 150V.  My dad is an electrical engineer so I'm not entirely solo as he will help me.  Especially on the protection side.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Make sure you consider the maximum voltage of the panels in full sunlight (it's usually specified in the solar panel docs, "maximum open circuit voltage") not just nominal voltage

Answer (score 1):

I found the [user manual](https://www.ecoflow.com/us/support/download).

Unfortunately there's not much interesting stuff in there.

Since the battery is 48V and the solar panel voltage can rise up to 150V, there's probably a DC-DC converter in there to charge the battery, with charge current regulation.

Normally, if the product is sane, the 15A specification should mean the maximum current it will draw from the solar panels. So it should be possible to use panels capable of more current, and if there is a lot of sun, it would simply max out at 15A and take whatever power it can.

If it was a solar battery charger, well the simple ones just connect the panels to the battery, which have to be the same voltage. If these products are badly designed (ie, no monitoring of overcurrent), sure, they can fry if the solar panels are too powerful. But this one supports a wide voltage range, so it probably doesn't use such a simple circuit.

However, the documentation gives no details. It doesn't even say if it has an MPPT. I guess you'll have to ask the manufacturer.

Personally I'd get another brand with proper documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is use a separate current limiter to put in front of the unit. Units like that exist, but are unusual and expensive and hard to find. It's not a realistic option for ordinary users.

Or you can connect up more panels, and sit and watch to be sure it doesn't get up to 15A. That's also not a realistic option for ordinary users.

The current limit on units like this is pretty much a hard limit. If it could handle 20A in, they'd call it a 20A unit. Sometimes the unit can handle a '15A' panel that is new, and cold, and runs at 16.5A, (You can ask the supplier about that) and sometimes you may find a 15A unit de-rated to '13.5A' for special purposes, but it's never going to be 20A for a 15A unit.